# How to I write an msbuild condition that applies to all of my web projects?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

I want to write a `Directory.Build.props` file that has a `Condition` in it that evaluates to `True` when the project loading it is an ASP .NET Core web project and `False` otherwise.

Directory.Build.props file:

```xml
<Project>
  <ItemGroup Condition="Condition Here">
    <!-- Stuff I want to do in web projects -->
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I've tried things like `Condition="'$(OutputType)'='Exe'"` for console projects and it worked but I'm not sure what to use for web projects.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`UsingMicrosoftNETSdkWeb` property](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/772f2a923c4b9f279a22f7c991a089622ddafbe2/src/Web/Sdk/Sdk.props#L17) that is set to `true` whenever a project is using `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"`.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(UsingMicrosoftNETSdkWeb)' == 'True'">
   <!-- Stuff I want to do in web projects -->
</ItemGroup>
```